# i want to compare the data in a PDF file with the flat file by using unix terminal

Tags: unix, pdf, flat-file

I want to compare the data in the PDF file with the flat file by using unix terminal. Is it possible to do so by writing any script.

Comment: What is a flat file? And are pdfs not flat?

Comment: sorry, I want to compare the date in a pdf file and a .txt file. Is it possible?

Comment: To compare the textual data in a PDF with the data in a .txt file, you first have to extract the text from the PDF and then compare the extracted text with your text file (in a somewhat lax manner as certain aspects of PDFs can arbitrarily be interpreted by text extractors). What you should ask for, therefore, is a *PDF text extraction utility*. Beware, though, there are PDFs which do not contain the information required for regular text extraction. In that case you may even have to render the PDF pages as images and apply OCR.

Comment: You should edit your question text to contain this extra information. Simply click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40885684/edit) link beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered .Please go through the link .

[Pdf compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469157/pdf-compare-on-linux-command-line)

Comment: I want to compare a pdf file with a flat file in unix. The above one is the compare of two pdfs.